# Implementing partial template specialization of template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, template-templates

I am having problems implementing the specialization of a class template that uses template template parameters. For example, I would like to write a class that is used for sorting:

```
template <template <typename, typename...> class container_type> struct SortTraits {

  template <class comparator_type>
  static void sort(container_type<size_t> &front, comparator_type comp) {
    std::sort(front.begin(), front.end(), comp);
  }
};


template <> struct SortTraits<std::list> {

  template <class T, class comparator_type>
  static void sort(std::list<T> &front, comparator_type comp) {
    front.sort(comp);
  }
};
```

Then I would call this as follows:

```
struct MyFunctor {
  bool operator()( const size_t& a, const size_t& b ) const {
    return a>b;
  }
};

//! Alias template used for the type of container used to store a front
template <class T> using container_template = std::list<T>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  //! Concrete type for a front
  typedef container_template<size_t> front_type;


  front_type myContainer = {3,5,2,6,3,6,7};

  MyFunctor mySortFunctor;

  SortTraits<container_template>::sort(myContainer, mySortFunctor);

  for (auto it = myContainer.begin(); it != myContainer.end(); ++it)
    cout<<" "<<*it;
  cout<<endl;
  exit(0);
}
```

I use the specialization for the list as I would like to call the sort function that the std::list implements. Yet, this code doesn't work. Why the template specialization is not being found?

The error I get is:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:3772:40: error: invalid operands
>         to binary expression ('std::__1::__list_iterator' and 'std::__1::__list_iterator')
>           difference_type __len = __last - __first;
>                                   ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~

And it's because it's not finding the specialization.

Comment: Which compiler you use? Works fine in gcc 4.8 and clang 3.4. And what is `myContainer` and `mySortFunctor`?

Comment: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: *"Yet, this code doesn't work.*" What exactly does not work?

Comment: This is an explicit (= full) specialization, not a partial specialization.

Comment: This code looks correct and in fact works in both clang and gcc.

Comment: Works indeed, I tried on a much simpler code and it works fine. But in my much harder code it doesn't really work yet. I need to figure out why the template specialization is not kicking in.

Comment: [Works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c3eacef32617595). You can't give us some working code and ask us "why doesn't my code work? Oh, by the way, it's not this code and I'm not showing it to you" and expect an answer.

Comment: The code doesn't work. Try it again using the alias template as shown in my modified post.

Comment: You can check that it works with std::vector but not with the std::list. Look here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5edb52d225cf0f97

Comment: Now, if instead of using the alias template, I specifically put std::list, then it works! So why using the alias template doesn't work in the first place? Is this because C++11 support is just recent? Look here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/680115bd97e2f72a

Comment: The specializations of an alias templates are aliases (= equivalent to what they refer to). The alias template itself is a *distinct* template.

Comment: So what? The code still works with a std::vector.

Comment: What I mean is that your specialization `template <> struct SortTraits<std::list>` will *only* match `SortTraits<std::list>` and not `template<class T> using list_alias = std::list<T>; SortTraits<list_alias>` Since the primary template is the fall-back, `SortTraits<std::vector>` and `template<class T> using vector_alias = std::vector<T>; SortTraits<vector_alias>` will both use the primary template.

Comment: Like @dyp says, `container_template` is a distinct template from `std::list`. [If you specialize the traits class for `container_template`, the program works as expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/efac8e78c55b00d7).

Comment: @Casey your code doesn't work either. If you change the line to `template <class T> using container_template = std::vector<T>;` the code you wrote stops working. The idea is for the user to choose from either std::vector or std::list (or any other container).

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon That's why it's a comment, and not an answer. The point is to demonstrate that the alias `container_template` is a distinct template from `std::list` and hence will not match the same specializations.

Comment: I understand. So I guess there's no way to do what I want to do with template aliases. I'm gonna have to resort back to using fully specialized types...

Answer (score 3):

Why bother with the traits class and the partial specialization at all instead of simply overloading a `sort` function? As the saying goes, `std::less` is more. ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32bb89faa15a16a1))

```
template <typename Container>
using less = std::less<
  typename std::decay<
    decltype(*std::declval<Container&>().begin())
  >::type
>;

template<typename Container, typename Compare = less<Container>>
inline void sort(Container& container, Compare&& comp = {}) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;
    std::sort(begin(container), end(container), std::forward<Compare>(comp));
}

template<typename... T, typename Compare = less<std::list<T...>>>
inline void sort(std::list<T...>& list, Compare&& comp = {}) {
    list.sort(std::forward<Compare>(comp));
}
```

For that matter, a generic `sort` function that prefers member `sort` when it exists would save you the trouble of writing overloads at all ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56071eeb5f82491c)):

```
namespace detail {
using std::begin;
using std::end;

template<typename Container, typename Compare>
inline void sort_(Container& container, Compare&& comp, ...) {
    std::sort(begin(container), end(container), std::forward<Compare>(comp));
}

template<typename Container, typename Compare>
inline auto sort_(Container& container, Compare&& comp, int) ->
  decltype(container.sort(std::forward<Compare>(comp))) {
    return container.sort(std::forward<Compare>(comp));
}

template<typename Container, typename Compare = std::less<
  typename std::decay<
    decltype(*begin(std::declval<Container&>()))
  >::type
>>
inline void sort(Container& container, Compare&& comp = {}) {
    sort_(container, std::forward<Compare>(comp), 0);
}
} // namespace detail
using detail::sort;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use type parameters?:

```
template<typename CONTAINER>
struct SortTraits
{
    template<typename COMPARATOR>
    static void sort( CONTAINER&  container , COMPARATOR comparator = std::less<> )
    {
        std::sort( std::begin( container ) , std::end( container ) , comparator );
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct SortTraits<std::list<T>>
{
    template<typename COMPARATOR>
    static void sort( std::list<T>&  list , COMPARATOR comparator )
    {
        list.sort( comparator );
    }
};

namespace utils
{
    template<typename CONTAINER , typename COMPARATOR>
    void sort( CONTAINER& container , COMPARATOR comparator )
    {
        SortTraits<CONTAINER>::sort( container , comparator );
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int,4> arr = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 };
    std::list<int> list = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 };
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 };

    utils::sort( arr );
    utils::sort( list );
    utils::sort( vec );
}
```

Comment: @T.C. how difficult could be to add one more type parameter to the specialization? Of course what I posted is only an example to guide the OP, I'm not going to post the entire library and do his/her work.

Comment: Because working with type parameters is the easy way out, for which I wouldn't have created this post in the first place. I wanted to try the template aliases instead, but it seems it's not trivial.